# Why 'ps' command works different in oracle Linux and CentOS

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to check whether the pmon process is running or not in CentOS and Oracle Linux over shell command. I used below command.

In CentOS :

```
 ps -e | grep pmon;echo $?
```

Output

```
61577 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_orcl
0
```

But, in Oracle Linux:

```
ps -e | grep pmon;echo $?
```

Output

```
1
```

I am not able to understand why they behave differently.
Can I get a command which will work on both OS as below

```
1 output for process not running 
0 output for process running
```

Comment: That's because in the first case there is a process matching `pmon`, and the second case there isn't, no? Also, you probably want `grep -q`.

Comment: Are you sure that in the second case, the process is running at all? Try `ps -e | grep init; echo $?`

Comment: Yes it is there [oracle@oel67ora111 ~]$ ps -aef | grep pmon
oracle   18160 15891  0 14:53 pts/4    00:00:00 grep pmon
oracle   59040     1  0 11:16 ?        00:00:01 ora_pmon_db1

Comment: ps -e | grep init; echo $? gives 1 in CentOS and gives 0 in Oracle Linux @AndreasFester

Comment: @AndreasFester Problem here -e not works properly in Oracle linux and second problem is it returns 0 even if process not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As suggested by Vatine and Dipak
Try running this

```
ps -ef|grep [p]mon|wc -l|awk '{if ($1 != 0) print "0"; else print "1";}'
```

It will return `1` if process is not running and `0` if it is running.

Comment: It still has the same difference in CentOS it gives 0 and in Oracle linux it gives 1

Comment: `ps -e | grep [p]mon` makes the need for `grep -v grep` go away (the regexp `[p]mon` matches the string "pmon", but doesn't match the string "[p]mon").

Comment: Thanks @Vatine. It is good to know and implement in future scenarios

Comment: Nice Vatine and Utsav it worked very well Thanks  @Vatine

Comment: @Dipak - I am not sure about `CentOS`, but could you do a `ps -ef|grep [p]mon` and compare the results on both OS to verify if there is a difference?

Comment: @Utsav no there is not any difference, Your answer was right just difference is of "-ef" instead "-e", In oracle linux i am not seen any output without  "-f" in ps command,  Please update your answer so that i can mark it accept